# Where is Dublin's (Ireland) city center and most ideal location for nightlife/pubs?

Tags: accommodation, nightlife, dublin

Any suggestions in which are one should stay in Dublin, Ireland (accommodation) to be within walking distance of any major central areas, night clubs, pubs, etc?

Comment: To go along with what Rory has said these locations may be helpful: [Temple Bar](http://www.dublinmapped.com/?search=Temple+Bar&plc=Y9RL7EH4AA) and [Grafton Street](http://www.dublinmapped.com/?search=Grafton&plc=TX2QI4YS29)

Comment: I'd say THE "centre" geographically is Bachelor's Walk by the Connell Street bridge. We stayed in a backpackers about 50 yards down the walk - chosen at semi random on internet! :-). Superb location and a few minutes walk from Temple Bar or Grafton street.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Temple Bar is generally considered the night life / pub / club centre of Dublin. There is a wide range of accommodation from hostels to quality hotels, and there are a vast number of pubs and clubs within crawling distance.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why is an area named like it is a bar?  Temple bar for me seems like just one bar, not an area :)

Comment: Wikipedia says "It probably got its name from the Temple family, who lived in the area in the 17th century; Sir William Temple, provost of Trinity College Dublin in 1609, had his house and gardens here." but gives no explanation for the 'Bar' bit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Bar,_Dublin

Comment: @KarlCassar It's an unrelated (or at least very loosely related) meaning of the word *bar*: *bar* as in a [city gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatehouse). It may be because such gates *barred* the way, but that may be just a divagation of mine. The word isn't used in this sense in modern English but remains in place names here and there in the British Isles. Temple Bar would have been a city gate, and then by extension the neighborhood near that city gate, and now the city has grown and the gate is forgotten but the name lives on.

Comment: Is there metro / good transportation near by? thanks

Comment: Sexy - have you looked at the map?

Comment: Coppers seems worth a visit - disclaimer: I only know of it from the "Can't Cope Won't Cope" TV Series. [Coppers website - warning: music starts playing on visit](http://copperfacejacks.ie/) Reference: [Can't Cope Won't Cope Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can%27t_Cope,_Won%27t_Cope).